# Distint factor of integers

Tags: prime-factorization

> I need to find the number of distinct factors of $500$.

$500=  5*100 = 5* (10*10) = 5* (5*2) * (5*2) = 2^2 * 5^3$. So, the total number of positive factors are $(2+1)*(3+1) = 12$.

But, as the question asked to find distinct factors, should I count negative factors also? Or should I only count the positive factors?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/NumberOfFactors.shtml

Comment: The question of whether you want to count only positive factors or if you allow negative factors is up to you and the question writer.  Both are viable interpretations.  If you do allow for negative factors then the same method applies.  Simply multiply by two as each positive factor is in direct correspondence with a negative and vice versa via an easy bijection.